# Create a selectInput in the form of selection bar for Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm still a beginner to shiny so I'm sorry if my question is counter-intuitive. For my shiny app, I have a selectInput to select different quarter of the year like this

```
selectInput("qtr", "Quarter", c("First quarter" = "Q1",
                          "Second quarter" = "Q2",
                          "Third quarter" = "Q3",
                          "Fourth quarter" = "Q4"))
```

My question is: is it possible to create a selectInput in the form of a selection bar like in the example below, as users click to filter date range ? By my understanding, it's neither Radio Buttons or Checkbox Group. Thank you in advance !

[image: Selection bar to choose date range]

Comment: `CheckBoxGroupButtons` from the `shinyWidgets` [package might do the trick](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It's exactly what I am looking for. One more question, do you have any idea how to adjust the style of the button like width, text and button color using CSS ? I wrap my CSS around the div and style arguement but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to pholzm's suggestion I think that radioGroupButtons from the shinywidgets package is well suited to what you want

Comment: Thanks for your replying. It's what I am looking for. As above, do you have any idea how to adjust the style of the button like width, text and button color using CSS ? I wrap my CSS around the div and style arguement but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `radioGroupButton` probably is better in this case. Regarding styling, you can e.g. add 
`tags$style(HTML(".radiobtn {background: yellow; color: red; border-color: #00F; font-weight: 800;}")),` somewhere in your ui to make radiobuttons yellow with bold red text and blue borders etc. To check class and properties of your widget, you can right-click>inspect on the element in your app.